# finding connected component in a 3d BW matrix - matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, 3d

im trying to find connected components in an image stack. it's basically 2d BW images stacked to a 3d matrix.
i've tried using bwconncomp, regionprops3 and bwareafilt but with no success.
my target is to get the centroids and size of the components, to eventually cut them to individual stacks.

can really use some help. thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to find 3d components in the stack, or 2d components in each plane of the stack? How have you tried the methods you mentioned? How did they fail to meet your expectations?

Comment: i'm trying to find 3d components in a stack.
i think i managed to do so eventually with regionprops3, i think we just used it incorrect the first time.
after i'll be sure that what we did worked i'll upload the solution

Comment: Depending on what output you need, you might look at [`bwlabeln`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwlabeln.html) as well.